# MacOS apache doesn't load php 8.3.1 mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, apache

I need help with including mongodb extension for php in apache on MacOs.
I installed php8.3.1, apache Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) and included mongodb extension in php (extension="/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20230831/mongodb.so"). Also included phpmodule in apache "LoadModule php_module /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so".

And when I check php modules in terminal I see mongodb there:

```
olegk@olg buddy-web % php -v
PHP 8.3.1 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2023 12:44:38) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

olegk@olg buddy-web % php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/8.3
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/8.3/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/8.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/8.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini

olegk@olg buddy-web % php -m
[PHP Modules]
....
mongodb
....
```

But when I checked phpinfo() I don't see mongodb module there
[screenshot of phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJd6D.png)

I tried already all possible things and it still not load mogodb in apache. Maybe you know where issue can be?

Comment: Ok, I found error in apache logs `mongodb.so not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.`, and when I do `codesign -s - mongodb.so` (this I found in google). I see another error `mongodb.so not valid for use in process: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not`. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will have this problem. [Here is link](https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/249) that helped me. Need to install httpd and it will not use extension validation.

mongodb.so will work there.

> Quick steps:
>
> 1. sudo apachectl stop <- stop default Apache2 from Apple
> 2. sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist <- remove default
>    Apache from launchd (autostart)
> 3. brew install httpd <- install apache2 from homebrew
> 4. sudo brew services start httpd
>
> Default port for Apache from brew is 8080 you should change it in the
> config files, also add at the end of the conf file Include
> /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf the config is located in
> /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).